# Getting Inputs from another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a table called say Employee_id. I want to loop the table data and for each row of the table data run some other query where the inputs will be the values from the row of employee_id.

Is it possible to write something like this in Access?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rsEmployees As DAO.Recordset
Dim stringName As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String

strSQL = "SELECT Employee_Name..., etc FROM Employee_id "

Set rsEmployees = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
rsEmployees.MoveFirst

Do While Not rsEmployees.EOF

stringName = rsEmployees!Employee_Name

strSQL1 = "What ever your query is"

Do.Cmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
rsEmployes.MoveNext

Loop 

End Sub
```

Set 1: Create a query that selects every record from the Employee_ID table

Set 2: While Loop through the recordset of the above Query

Set 3: Use rsEmployess!ColumnName to access each record field

Set 4: Use the above string in your query